# Jensen's integral inequality conditions

Tags: analysis

In Jensen's integral inequality $\phi\bigg(\dfrac{\int_A gf}{\int_A g}\bigg)\leq \dfrac{\int_A g\,\phi(f)}{\int_A g}$, let $\phi$ be convex on $(a,b)$, which contains the range of $f$. Assume $g$ is non-negative, and $\int_A g > 0$. My question is why is $\dfrac{\int_A gf}{\int_A g}$ guaranteed to be a quantity within $(a,b)$? I know it is within $[\inf(f), \sup(f)]$, but that may include $a,b$ which escape $(a,b)$?

The assumption on $f$ is Riemann integrable. Therefore $A$ could be taken as a closed interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is your assumption on $g$? Why is $\int_A g \neq 0$?

Comment: Are there any assumptions on $f$?

Comment: Where is the statement you quoting from?

Comment: If the quantity is $b$, then $f = b$ almost everywhere on the set where $g > 0$, so $f(x) = b$ for some $x$. Thus the quantity cannot be $b$. Similarly, it cannot be $a$.